# Wrong action button placement in XFCE dialogbox

Tags: user-interface, gtk3

Since the last big update including Xfce 4.16 (I'm running Arch Linux), the action buttons like Ok or Cancel are wrongly placed at the top of the window in most application's dialog boxes.

Here's an example with the Open File window in LibreOffice, I see the same behavior in other application like Firefox or Mousepad :

[image: Open dialogbox]
<sub>(source: [lps-it.fr](https://www.lps-it.fr/pub/screenshot_open-dialogbox.png))</sub>

This is very annoying as it breaks the ergonomic of the dialog box and make the user experience painful.

I believe this is coming from GTK3 but I'm not sure.
Do you know which component is to blame for this, and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/DialogsUseHeader -s false
```

Will move them back to the bottom. See: [Arch Wiki Xfce Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xfce#Reverting_Client-Side_Decorations)